# How to get started with developing WCF web service with MonoDevelop?

Tags: mono, monodevelop

How to get started in developing WCF web service with MonoDevelop, is there any project templates?

My experience is with Eclipse - Java Servlet approach, however I need to develop WCF web service using C# now, any one can give hint as to where to start.

I know my question is quite broad, as there are many types of web service that can be built with WCF, I am just after for some place to start with WCF.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend a very good alternative for WCF: [ServiceStack.NET](http://www.servicestack.net/). As stated by the author...

> A modern, code-first, DTO-driven, WCF replacement web services framework encouraging best-practices for creating DRY, high-perfomance, scalable REST web services.

It's currently my choice for developing web services that run smoothly on IIS or on linux servers.

Documentation is very good and Demis (the author) has been very helpful on answering [questions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/servicestack) posted by the community.